# My suffix is western, from a "western" perspective

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My suffix is western, from a "western" perspective 
My prefix a strange domain, unless you know Latin 
My infix a greeting, modernly its excitement subjective 
My whole's population growth did recently flatten

hint:

> domain references a TLD, if you don't know the acronym: https://bfy.tw/P5CB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the clues are in descending order of difficulty, let's do this one backwards:

My whole's population growth did recently flatten

> Must be **China**. Let's see if we can't cram the rest of the clues in..

My infix a greeting, modernly its excitement subjective

> c**hi**na

My prefix a strange domain, unless you know Latin

> ch is the top level domain for Switzerland, from "the Confederation of Helvetia", or more historically accurately, the Latin version thereof

My suffix is western, from a "western" perspective

> NA, for North America, is the western part of the occident, or "the west" as it's also called.

Comment: I didn't realize they were in descending order of difficulty. Given that globally most (large nations) population growth curves have flattened, I thought the prefix and infix were the most telling clues. I guess China is just what comes to mind for the stark drop in growth rate. Regardless, nicely done, you're correct